# How to mock inside a function by using phpunit

Tags: mocking, phpunit

My question is:

I want to test 'getThirdPayUrl' by mocking the 'getThirdPayUrlSpec', how do I create a mock class with phpunit?

```
class BasePayController{
    public static function getThirdPayUrl($type,$order,$arr,&$url){
        //$objCtrl = new AliPayController();
        $objCtrl = self::getPayController($type);
        $ret =  $objCtrl->getThirdPayUrlSpec($order,$arr,$url);
        return $ret;
    }   
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [PHPUnit Manual](http://phpunit.de/manual/3.0/en/mock-objects.html) has a section with examples for Mock's.  Start here and then if you are having issues, please post a more detailed question.

Basically, your test will Mock the BasePayController, and will return a hard set URL for testing.

```
<?php
require_once 'BasePayController.php';

class BasePayControllerTest extends PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase
{
    public function testThirdPartyURL()
    {
        // Create a stub 
        $stub = $this->getMockBuilder('BasePayController')
                     ->disableOriginalConstructor()
                     ->getMock();

        // Configure the stub.
        $stub->expects($this->any())
             ->method('getThirdPayUrl')
             ->will($this->returnValue('http://Dummy.com/URLToTest'));

        // Test the Stub
        $this->assertEquals('http://Dummy.com/URLToTest', $stub->getThirdPartyUrl());
    }
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

My solution is as follows，first php need to install a plug-in named php-test-helper

```
class BasePayControllerTest extends PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase
{
    protected function setUp()
    {
        $this->getMock(
          'AliPayContoller',                    /* name of class to mock     */
          array('getThirdPayUrlSpec'),          /* list of methods to mock   */
          array(),                              /* constructor arguments     */
          'AliPayMock'                             /* name for mocked class     */
        );

        set_new_overload(array($this, 'newCallback'));   //php-test-helper  plug-in
    }

    protected function tearDown()
    {
        unset_new_overload();      //php-test-helper plug-in
    }

    protected function newCallback($className)
    {
        switch ($className) {
            case 'AliPayContoller': return 'AliPayMock';
            default:    return $className;
        }
    }

    public function testgetThirdPayUrl()
    {
        $foo = new BasePayController;
        $this->assertTrue($foo->getThirdPayUrl());
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: **Note:** [the Test-Helper extension is superseded](https://twitter.com/s_bergmann/status/457816903881588736) by https://github.com/krakjoe/uopz